# Can react-select underline searched text in filtered options?

Tags: react-select

I want to create react-select that when user type text, it will show filtered options whose part of match texts are underlined and change color from black to red as provided below image. Is it possible? Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0):

After a while, I get the answer :)

```
import Select, { components } from 'react-select';

const options1 = [
  {
    value: 'chocolate',
    label: 'chocolate',
  },
  {
    value: 'strawberry',
    label: 'strawberry',
  },
  {
    value: 'vanilla',
    label: 'vanilla'
  }
]

class MyOption extends React.Component {
  f_search = (input,option) => {
    const num = option.indexOf(input)
    const len = input.length
    return (
    <div>
      <span>{option.substr(0, num)}</span>
      <span style={{color:"red", textDecoration: "underline"}}>{input}</span>
      <span>{option.substr(num +len)}</span>
    </div>
    )
  }
  render() {
    const input = this.props.selectProps.inputValue
    const option = this.props.data.label
    return (
      <components.Option {...this.props}>
        {this.f_search(input,option)}
      </components.Option>
    )
  }
}

const ReactSelect7 = () =>
  <Select options={options1} components={{ Option: MyOption }} />
```

Comment: not working, it returns additional characters